# Fetch data from entry with particular key from JSON array with jq

Tags: json, jq

How do we fetch the `email` from the entry whose `level` key has the value `2` from the below JSON document?

The expected output is

```
jeenav.b@xy.com
```

Any suggestion, please?

```json
{
  "escalation_policy": {
    "on_call": [
      {
        "level": 2,
        "start": "2022-05-25T00:30:00Z",
        "end": "2022-05-25T09:30:00Z",
        "user": {
          "id": "ABOKC",
          "name": "Jaavena Dobey",
          "email": "jeenav.b@xy.com",
          "time_zone": "Tokyo"
        }
      },
      {
        "level": 7,
        "start": "2022-05-23T01:00:00Z",
        "end": "2022-05-30T01:00:00Z",
        "user": {
          "id": "KLSPSP",
          "name": "kosls frank",
          "email": "kosl.ka@xy.com",
          "time_zone": "Tokyo"
        }
      },
      {
        "level": 3,
        "start": "2022-05-23T01:00:00Z",
        "end": "2022-05-30T01:00:00Z",
        "user": {
          "id": "SKSPSLSL",
          "name": "Smitha Choudhary",
          "email": "sri.choudhary@xy.com",
          "time_zone": "Tokyo"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this,

1. Get the array of the objects.
2. Select the ones where level is 2
3. Of the array returned, print the user's email

Invocation and output,

```
$ jq ".escalation_policy.on_call[] | select( .level == 2) | .user.email" test.json
"jeenav.b@xy.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following gets one of the email addresses of the people on call, namely the *first* one with an escalation policy on call level equal of 2:

```bash
jq -r '.escalation_policy.on_call | map(select(.level == 2))[0].user.email' file
```

You didn't ask for this specifically, but the following gives you the email address of the on-call person with the *lowest* `.level`.  We do this by sorting the `on_call` array and returning the `.user.email` value from the entry that sorts first:

```bash
jq -r '.escalation_policy.on_call | sort_by(.level)[0].user.email' file
```

We could also make sure that the current time is within the `.start` and `.end` timestamps.  We do this by selecting only the relevant on-call entries before sorting them as before:

```bash
jq -r '
    .escalation_policy.on_call |
    map(select( now > (.start|fromdate) and now < (.end|fromdate) )) |
    sort_by(.level)[0].user.email' file
```

We can do this because we're lucky enough to have dates in exactly the format that the `fromdate` function in `jq` expects.